# Python: How to keep the excel function result when convert .xlsx to .csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

For instance, I have a cell R1 in .xlsx defined as `"=SUM(Q1:Q2)"`, `Q1 = 1` and `Q2 = 2`, so `R1` is `3` in .xlsx. When I run this code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('moederfile/moederfile.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_names[1])
csv_file = open('moederfile/sum.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow([sheet.cell(row=1, column=18).value])

your_csv_file.close()
```

The generated .csv  gave a `null` instead of 3, I wonder how to fix this issue. Other possible methods to getting the result of the excel function is welcomed as well. Because I tried to read from the .xlsx directly but it ended up with same thing...

Comment: Not sure exactly what functions that is possible, but maybe you can copy the cell values and paste them over the cells (overwriting the current excelfunctions). In Excel you can do that to remove the function but keep the value

Comment: Well, I would like to do it with python without modifying the excel sheet. But thx anyways.

Comment: So you do not have any ways to change the contents in python?

Comment: Well the idea is like: I got a .xlsx file which has some predefined functions inside. Then I insert my inputs to the excel using python and let excel do the calculation. In the end I just need to read the result cells and output them. I know this is kinda dumb but somehow I would like to know if there is a possible way to achieve it. I have tried openpyxl and xlsxwriter, none of them work.